# Error shutting down Windows XP machine with RPC

Tags: permissions, windows-xp, rpc, shutdown

I have an Ubuntu server on the same LAN with a Windows XP Professional machine. 
I'm trying to issue the following command from the server to shutdown 
the machine:

```
net rpc shutdown -I 192.168.X.X -U <username>%<password> -r -f
```

but I get the error :

```
Could not connect to server 192.168.X.X
The user name or password was not correct. 
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

The credentials are correct, checked it several times. What can be the problem? 
I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps <username> must be prefixed with the windows domain or workstation name (i.e. the scope within which the username is defined):

> *domain*\*username*